# Random distribution of N points with a specified average spacing?

Tags: python, random

This is probably a question of logic more than an algorithm. I want to distribute about N points in such a way that the average distance of a single point to the other N-1 points is uniformly distributed around a value **d**. That is, The points themselves are not be normally distributed but their spacing with respect to each other is.

Is there a logical way to implement this?

For Example :

```
X = np.ones(N) #1d for simplicity
d = np.ones(N)

for i in range(N):
    X[i] = ## Insert the algorithm here 
       ##

for i in range(N):
    da = 0 
    for j in range(N):
        if i != j:
            da += np.sqrt(np.abs(X[i]**2 - X[j]**2))  #Calculating distance to other points and 
                                                        summing up
            
    
    da = da / (N-1) # Taking average of all distances
    
    d[i] = da  # the average distance of point i with all other points 

A = np.mean(d) #The mean of all average distances
```

A is the parameter I want control over. It should be basis for how all the points are distributed.Recommendations using inbuilt Python or C modules would work as well.

Comment: This is probably a good question for stat.stackexchange.com as well.  I think it's been asked there before but was never answered - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398617/distance-between-points-in-a-sample-follow-normal-distribution

Comment: What does uniform distribution around a value d mean? When I think uniform distribution, doesn't it usually involve a range such as [0,1], like some bounds? Suppose d=1, what does this mean?

Comment: My bad. I mean a normal distribution (edited it). So say I have a normal/gaussian distribution, d is the mean value (mu). So if d = 0.3, the Gaussian is centered at 0.3. (with some standard deviation).

Comment: Normal doesn't seem likely. Distance is a positive measure, and the support for a normal is -∞ to ∞. Whatever the distribution is it would be bounded below by zero.

Comment: You could randomly select a starting point and then randomly pick offsets from that starting point to generate the remaining points.